# Best practice for closing a cursor and connection to a SQLite database?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm writing a simple function that executes a SQL statement. Have I structured the function correctly so that the cursor and connection are closed? It does return the expected result.

```py
import sqlite3

DATABASE_PATH = "flex_database.db"

select_final_assignments = """
SELECT * FROM final_assignments
"""

def execute_select_statement_1(connection, statement):
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(statement)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close() 
    return result

def main():
    connection = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_PATH)
    result = execute_select_statement(connection, select_final_assignments)
    print(f"{result}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I also tried structuring the function a second way, but the result printed as `<generator object execute_select at 0x7f65a8e44a50>`. If this is the better way to structure the function?

```py
def execute_select_statement_2(DATABASE_PATH, statement):
    with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(statement)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
        return result
```

Comment: `fetchall` gives generator and you should use `for row in result` to work with every row separatelly or `list(result)` to get all rows at once.

Comment: I have corrected the indentation. `cursor.fetchall()` should be part of `with` block. Otherwise context manager will close the `cursor`, before you get the result.